# Scripting Netplan for static IP address

Tags: scripts, netplan

I've posted in the forum but thought I would ask here also.
So, I am new to Ubuntu Server 18.04, netplan and .yaml. In the past using Ubuntu Server 16.04 I was able to create a pretty decent shell script to setup a static IP on a server in a post-installation setup.
Is it not possible to script out the network configuration now that Ubuntu Server 18.04 is using netplan?
I was trying to tweak my shell script to configure the writing to the .yaml file but it seems formatting is crucial when editing a .yaml file and I was not having much luck. It seems Ansible may possibly be a solution for this, possibly? But I've yet to master Ansible.
Anyone else have any luck writing a script to configure a static IP using netplan and updating the .yaml file?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried it? It shouldn't be a problem when using a heredoc within the shell script for instance.

Comment: Would heredoc work with the specific formatting of the .yaml file?

Comment: yes, it would work with any special text file formatting.

Answer (score 3):

@TygerTy Thanks for that. I forgot to post a follow up a few weeks ago. This is what I came up with that worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Creates a backup
cp /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml.bk_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
# Changes dhcp from 'yes' to 'no'
sed -i "s/dhcp4: yes/dhcp4: no/g" /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# Retrieves the NIC information
nic=`ifconfig | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`
# Ask for input on network configuration
read -p "Enter the static IP of the server in CIDR notation: " staticip 
read -p "Enter the IP of your gateway: " gatewayip
read -p "Enter the IP of preferred nameservers (seperated by a coma if more than one): " nameserversip
echo
cat > /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml <<EOF
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    $nic
      addresses:
        - $staticip
      gateway4: $gatewayip
      nameservers:
          addresses: [$nameserversip]
EOF
sudo netplan apply
echo "==========================="
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, although I'm generating a static from the current config (don't ask why).

Just substitute the IP address for your static IP and netmask instead of dynamically looking for it like I do.

You could also change the network manager as well.

**createStaticConnection.sh**
 
------ 

`END_CONFIG=/etc/netplan/01-network-card.yaml

generateAndApply() {
    sudo netplan generate
    sudo netplan apply
}

getInternetInfo() {
    local INTERNET_INFO=$( ip r | grep default )
    printf "%s" "$( echo $INTERNET_INFO | cut -f$1 -d' ' )"
}

#static information
NAMESERVERS=("1.1.1.1" "1.0.0.1")
NETWORK_MANAGER="NetworkManager"

# information that varies
IP="$( ip r | grep kernel | cut -f9 -d' ' )"
GATEWAY="$( getInternetInfo 3 )"
DEVICE_NAME="$( getInternetInfo 5 )"
METHOD="$( getInternetInfo 7 )"
PREFIX="$( ip r | grep kernel | cut -f1 -d' ' | cut -f2 -d'/' )"

createStaticYAML() {
   local YAML="network:\n"
    YAML+="    version: 2\n"
    YAML+="    renderer: $NETWORK_MANAGER\n"
    YAML+="    ethernets:\n"
    YAML+="        $DEVICE_NAME:\n"
    YAML+="            dhcp4: no\n"
    YAML+="            addresses: [$IP/$PREFIX]\n"
    YAML+="            gateway4: $GATEWAY\n"
    YAML+="            nameservers:\n"
    YAML+="                addresses: [${NAMESERVERS[0]},${NAMESERVERS[1]}]"
    printf "%s" "$YAML"
}

clearConfigs() {
    [ -f $END_CONFIG ] && sudo rm $END_CONFIG
}

setYAML() {
    sudo echo -e "$(createStaticYAML)" > $END_CONFIG
}

clearConfigs
setYAML
generateAndApply
restartNetwork`